# Как использовать один экземпляр DbContext?(IUnitOfWork)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, шаблоны-проектирования, проектирование

В EF DbContext и DbSet, вообще говоря, реализуют из коробки соответственно UnitOfWork и Repository. В интернете тысячи примеров как люди следуя четко по букварям оборачивает их руками в свои классы, которые реализуют свои интерфейсы.Что-то вроде этого:

```
public interface IUnitOfWork : IDisposable
{
    IRepository<T> GetRepository<T>() where T : class;
    void SaveAllChanges();
}
 public interface IRepository<T> : IDisposable
    where T : class
{
    IQueryable<T> Entities();
    void Update(T entity);
    void Add(T entity);
    void Remove(T entity);
    bool Contains(T entity);
}
```

Получается своего рода абстракция над абстракцией, во многих местах пишут что этого не следует делать, но нигде примера реализации как правильно нет. Я имею проект на трехслойке, изначально сделал так же через repo и uow, позже убрал репозитории и uow, но при добавлении объектов из разных классов к друг другу ловлю:
**System.InvalidOperationException: "Не удалось определить связь между двумя объектами, поскольку они привязаны к разным объектам ObjectContext."**
 Как я понимаю, это из за того что я каждый раз объявляю новый экземпляр контекста данных, вот что у меня щас в БЛЛ:

```
 public class EntityService : IEntityService
 {
    private MyContext db;
    public EntityService(string connectionString)
    {
        db = new MyContext(connectionString);
     }
    ...
}
```

Как мне правильно передавать один экземпляр контекста данных вовсе подобные сервисы без явной повторной реализации UoW?

Comment: _Не удалось определить связь между двумя объектами, поскольку они привязаны к разным объектам ObjectContext._ - может, просто нужно `Detach` объекта от одного контекста, потом `Attach` к другому контексту?

Comment: @Alexander Petrov по-моему такое решение будет слишком костыльным или нет?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно передавать в конструктор `DbContext` который будет возвращать какой-нибудь DI-контейнер. В самом контейнере уже настроить жизненный цикл объекта

```
private DbContext db;

public EntityService(DbContext context)
{
   db = context;
}
```

В контейнерах регистрируем `MyContext` для `DbContext`. Если уверенны, что тип вашего зарегистрированного контекста не поменяется, то можно еще и приведение сделать

```
private MyContext db;

public EntityService(DbContext context)
{
   db = (MyContext)context;
}
```

Comment: "В контейнерах регистрируем MyContext для DbContext." я так понимаю эту зависимость можно сделать через Ninject, но он что-то не хочет этого делать.

Comment: Да, можно и через Ninject. MyContext наследует DbContext?

Comment: Да, наследует, но регистрировать зависимость не хочет

Comment: @Devoli а как вы пробовали? Так 'kernel.Bind<DbContext>().To<MyContext>(). '?

Comment: Upd. Вроде получилось сделать зависимость,делал так же как у вас, а что у нас должно быть в DI-контейнере?

Comment: @Devoli еще регистрируете сервисы и в последствии используете их через интерфейсы.Там после точки надо указать время жизни обьекта

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58961/discussion-between-vadim-prokopchuk-and-devoli).

Answer (score 6):

Если пропустить промежуточные стадии, то вариантов два (с половиной):

### Вариант 1

Если вы не пишете тесты, то вам вообще не нужна абстракция `IRepository` в таком виде. Создавайте контекст на самом верху, в методе, который у вас соответствует одной бизнес-операции, связывайте объекты друг с другом, потом один раз вызывайте `SaveChanges` - и EF сам разберется.

Это идеология, заложенная в EF, и попытки пойти против нее вызывают много кода и боль.

### Вариант 1.01

Вариант, привычный со времен NHibernate - сделать контекст на запрос (от пользователя), положить в `HttpContext` (напрямую или через IoC) и более-менее споконо жить до момента, когда вам придется провести две раздельных операции за один запрос. Или записать ошибку операции в лог. Когда момент наступит - переписать на `[ThreadStatic]` / `<AsyncLocal>` и жить дальше.

### Вариант 2

Если вам нужны и UoW, и тесты, и репозиторий (ради тестов и ради локализации запросов), то придется наворачивать что-то вроде:

Интерфейс IoW в качестве точки доступа к репозиториям:

```
public interface IUnitOfWork : IDisposable
{
    IEntity1Repository Entity1Repository { get; }
    IEntity2Repository Entity2Repository { get; }

    void Save();
}
```

Его реализацию в виде

```
public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
{
    static AsyncLocal<UnitOfWork> _root = new AsyncLocal<UnitOfWork>();

    private readonly SomeModel _context;

    public UnitOfWork()
    {
        if (_root.Value == null)
        {
            this._context = new SomeModel();
            _root.Value = this;
        }
        else
        {
            this._context = _root.Value._context;
        }
    }

    public void Save()
    {
        if (_root.Value == this)
        {
            _context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }

    public IEntity1Repository Entity1Repository => new Entity1Repository(_context);

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (_root.Value == this)
        {
            _context.Dispose();
            _root.Value = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Т.к. вам захочется мокать репозитории и контекст, то придется добавить интерфейс для создания UoW:

```
public interface IUnitOfWorkFactory
{
    IUnitOfWork Create();
}
```

вставлять его в виде зависимостей в сервисы и использовать примерно так:

```
public class SomeService : ISomeService
{
    [Dependency]
    public IUnitOfWorkFactory UoWFactory { get; set; }

    public List<Entity1> GetAllEntitiesList()
    {
        using (var uow = UoWFactory.Create())
        {
            // добавить вызов Save в тех методах, которые действительно что-то меняют
            return uow.Entity1Repository.GetAll();
        }
    }
}
```

и мокать примерно так:

```
var list = new List<Entity1> { new Entity1() };

var repo = Mock.Of<IEntity1Repository>(repo => repo.GetAll() == list);
var uow = Mock.Of<IUnitOfWork>(u => u.Entity1Repository == repo);
var uowFactory = Mock.Of<IUnitOfWorkFactory>(f => f.Create() == uow);

var service = new SomeService() { UoWFactory = uowFactory };

var result = service.GetAllEntitiesList();

CollectionAssert.AreEqual(list, result);
```

Ссылка по теме, с кучей других вариантов вставки: [Survey of Entity Framework Unit of Work Patterns](https://lostechies.com/derekgreer/2015/11/01/survey-of-entity-framework-unit-of-work-patterns/)

Comment: А можно по-подробнее про 1 способ? Не совсем понял его реализацию. А что насчет 2 способа, изначально имел похожую реализацию, только вместо фабрик использовал Ninject.

Comment: @Devoli первый способ - это просто использовать context как есть. Без репозиториев и прочих оберток.