# В чем польза репозитория?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net

Например, избавился я от упоминания базы данных в контроллере, вынес все функции и методы в отдельный класс. И что? В чём печеньки? Стал мой контроллер тощим, а репозиторий раздулся  - мои плюсы каковы? Плюсы приложения каковы? Где прибыло в скорости,  или может в читаемости, или производительности? Сразу оговорюсь, не буду менять mssql на mysql ...

Comment: Плюсы в слабой связанности

Comment: @AGS17 что нам дает слабая связанность ? Почему , следуя заветам,  я должен носиться от класса к классу , чтобы понять , что функция,  или метод,  исполняет в каждом конкретном случае ?

Comment: 1. В резюме можно написать: владею шаблонами проектирования. 2. Кода стало больше - можно говорить работодателю, что много работаешь. Можно всем говорить, что создаёшь большие серьёзные приложения.

Comment: @Alexander Petrov  - вот именно , кроме "умности" больше не вижу плюсов . Правда пока не оценил плюсы ответа на вопрос , попробую сформировать вопрос немного по другому , с примерами , как писал в ответах  - жаль что не можем в комментах оперировать конкретно кодом ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Чтобы понять, зачем вообще затеяно заделение, нужно понять, что такое контроллер, и что такое репозиторий.

Когда-то было принято писать весь код в одном большом файле. Или в одном большом классе.

И это себя вполне оправдывало для небольших приложений. Т.е. если у вас есть калькулятор с памятью, то гораздо проще написать:

```
textBoxTesult.Text = Int32.Parse(textBoxInput.Text) + ExecuteScalar("SELECT TOP 1 SavedValue FROM CalcMemory");
```

К сожалению для больших приложений это быстро приводит к дикой мешанине в коде.

Поэтому код попытались разделить на три отдельных части:

- Presentation - Отображение данных, редиректы, реакция на клики пользователей, и прочие вещи, которые специфичны именно для UI, и не имеют прямого отношения к операциям над сущностями.
- Business Logic - операции над сущностями в вашей предметной области, желательно без привязки к тому, как и где именно эти данные хранятся.
- Data Access - доступ к данным.

И под это разделение придумали кучу паттернов.

MVC - это паттерн Presentation Layer. Его реализация ASP.NET MVC предполагает что вы разбиваете ваш Presentation на две с половиной части:

- View - отображение, с использованием шаблонизатора (Razor)
- Controller - класс-обработчик событий от пользователя, который занимается валидацией, редиректами и инициирует выборку данных из Model. Может быть еще отображает сырые данные из BL в классы для переноса данных во View. Никакой бизнес-логики в контроллере нет.
- Model - все остальное приложение. В случае трехуровневой архитектуры - Model - это уровень BL.

Плюсы такого разделения:

- Операции над сущностями больше никак не привяазны к пользовательскому интерфейсу, и при написании кода работы с ними вам не приходится думать, в каком из обработчиков клика вам надо вносить изменения и как отреагирует UI на написанный код. BL сам по себе, UI сам по себе.
- Контроллер перестает заниматься BL, начитает отвечать только за логику UI, и его гораздо проще покрыть юнит-тестами.

Ваш вопрос возник из-за того, что разделение на Controller и Model у вас изначально не было. У вас был класс с именем "контроллер", в котором у вас была написана бизнес-логика.

---

Ок, что такое репозиторий. [Классический паттерн Repository](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html) не имеет почти никакого отношения к тому, что сейчас называют репозиторием, по крайней мере при разработке на C#. Сам по себе классический Repository решает следующую проблему:

> Mediates between the domain and data mapping layers using a collection-like interface for accessing domain objects.

Наиболее близкое к репозиторию в современном коде на C# - это метод `IQueryProvider.Execute<TResult>`, который реализует EF - т.к. он делает ровно то, что написано в определении паттерна.

То, что вы называете репозиторием - это, скорее, репозиторий запросов. Он решает следующие проблемы:

- На код, работающий напрямую с EF (т.е. с `IQueryable`) - тяжело писать юнит тесты, т.к. подменить сразу весь контекст - тяжело. Воспросизвести поведение контекста при сложных операциях - вообще нереально.
- Код запросов начинает дублироваться по проекту, т.к. везде можно взять и написать `context.SomeEntities.Where(e => e.IsExpired and some long condition).ToList()`, и это проще, чем искать по проекту похожий запрос и куда-то (куда?) его выносить.
- поведение `IQueryable` сильно отличается от поведения `IEnumerable` при некоторых операциях (например, `null` по другому обрабатывается), и разработчику приходится напрягать мозг при виде каждого запроса в коде.

Поэтому проблему обычно решают радикально:

- Запрещают работать с контекстом напрямую в коде
- Выносят все запросы в отделный класс (классы), который называют Репозиторий
- Запрещают выдавать из репозитория `IQueryable`, разрешают только `IEnumerable`

---

На выходе получается:

- Контроллеры, которые занимаются только UI, и на которые можно легко написать тесты
- BL, которая работает только с уже выбранными (через репозиторий) объектами, и в которой нет проклятого `IQueryable`, и на которую можно написать тесты
- Репозитории, в которых нет особой логики, кроме фильтрации (которую можно подпереть интеграционными тестами)

Почему так не делают в небольших приложениях и почему все примеры смело создают контекст прямо из контроллера, лезут в него и выдают сущности прямо во View? Потому что это примеры, а не живые приложения. Никому не интересно будет смотерть на 5 классов ради того, чтобы показать новые фишки движка для View.

У вас сейчас нет BL, тесты вы скорее всего не пишете, приложение небольшое - и поэтому никакого выигрыша от разделения вы не получаете. И это нормально. Но если вы на проекте не один, если проект развивается и если бизнес логика в нем вообще есть (бывают исключения) - то варианты "дергаем репозитории из контроллера" или "дергаем контекст из контроллера" быстро приведут проект вникуда.

Comment: @Etkiner для общего понимания почитай также [ответ PashaPash на близкий вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/667414/213987) вариант 1, цитирую: "если вы не пишете тесты -- репозиторий вам не нужен"

Answer (score 0):

Можно выделить несколько самых значимых плюсов:

1. Использование в контроллерах только интерфейсов репозитория, что дает нам слабую связанность кода. Т.е. работая с интерфейсом вы знаете, что метод есть и он имеет реализацию.
2. Возможность использования DI-контейнеров. Позволяет вам изменять поведение классов по всей программе. Вы просто регистрируете другую реализацию, не изменяя код ваших контроллеров.
3. Возможность тестирования. Используя интерфейс, вам не обязательно иметь базу данных для проведения тестирования. Достаточно написать класс, для имитации БД.
4. Логика работы с БД зафиксирована. Например, при добавлении новой записи в БД с конкретным значением, необходимо будет сделать дополнительную запись в логах БД. Согласитесь, не удобно писать это в контроллере каждый раз. Вероятность забыть написать не отменяется.
5. Можно написать обобщенный репозиторий и использовать его. Необходимо расширить функции репозитория? Не проблема, берем наследуемся и дописываем/переопределяем методы. Это уменьшит количество кода и вероятность ошибки.
6. При использовании репозитория, мы можем уйти от явной привязки к одному хранилищу данных и тем самым повысить гибкость приложения.

---

> Плюсы приложения каковы

При использовании репозитория большим плюсом станет то, что вы разделили логику работы с БД и их обработкой, что в дальнейшем уменьшит время на исправление ошибок связанных с работой БД.

> Где прибыло в скорости, или может в читаемости , или
>   производительности

В читаемости и в производительности. Компилятор будет генерировать меньше IL кода. Вы не повторяете логику работы в каждом методе. Она находится в одном месте.

Comment: начнём по порядку   
пункт 1 ответа : работая с методом или функцией в контроллере  - я вижу его(её) реализацию ?  
пункт 2 ответа : относится к тому моменту, если в нескольких контроллерах я использую один и тот же принцип реализации своей задумки ... а если мои контроллеры разделены   , один отвечает за регистрацию , второй отвечает за работу с пользовательскими данными , если пользователь зарегистрирован и тд и тп ..

Comment: @Eikhner работая с интерфейсом вы не видите реализацию, а только знаете что она есть. Вы же можете наследовать интерфейс двум разным классам и уже выбирать какой инжектить. п.2 Тут не логика контроллера, а логика работы с БД. Например есть `UserRepository` и в нем метод `GetById`. В контроллере вы просто вызываете этот метод, а в `UserRepositrory` уже делаете все необходимое. И кстати источник информации может быть как БД, так и текстовый файл. В `UserRepository` вы определяете как искать информацию

Comment: друга , что мне мешает написать всё ,  о чём вы говорите,  в контроллере ? Плохо что на форуме не предусмотрена возможность вести диалог с использованием кода непосредственно ... И что напишет компилятор IL кода , когда из разных мест контроллера мы обратимся к одной и той же функции или методу репозитория ???

Comment: чем отличается запрос id сущности из репозитория , и тот же самый запрос id сущности из контроллера  - il код у них как то будет различаться ?

Comment: Дублирование кода и вероятность потерять логику.

Comment: Нет,  у одинакового кода IL е будет различаться. Просто репозиторий это провайдер между данными и их контроллером. Данные могут быть записаны в БД, в файле, как угодно

Comment: IL  код у них как то будет различаться? У запроса id сущности из контроллера или репозитория ?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59065/discussion-between-vadim-prokopchuk-and-eikhner).

Comment: @downvoters, почему заминусовали?